# Chaining extra Sweet Alerts based on if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I'm trying to create a step by step form using [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/), and I need to be able to add an extra step in my chaining based on an if statement.

For example, on my third modal I may have a radio question that says 'Will you be bringing a plus 1?', and if the user selects 'true' I need it to pop up with a extra stage asking 'name of plus one', if the user selects false then just continue.

```
swal.mixin({
        confirmButtonText: 'Next &rarr;',
        showCancelButton: true,
        progressSteps: ['1', '2', '3', '4']
      }).queue([
        {
            title: 'Which event?',
            text: 'Please start by selecting the event you would like to book in!',
            input: 'select',
            inputClass: 'swal-select-event',
            inputPlaceholder: 'Please Select',
            inputOptions: {
                '1' : 'Dance Event',
                '2' : 'Football Event'
            },
            inputValidator: (value) => {
                return new Promise((resolve) => {
                  if (value === '') {
                    resolve('You need to select an event!')
                  } else {
                    resolve()
                  }
                })
            }
        },
        {
            title: 'What Day?',
            text: 'Which day are they due to come in?',
            html:'<input id="swal-booking-date-select" type="date"/>',
            preConfirm: () => {
                return document.getElementById('swal-booking-date-select').value
            },
            inputValidator: (value) => {
                return new Promise((resolve) => {
                  if (value === '') {
                    resolve('You need to select a date!')
                  } else {
                    resolve()
                  }
                })
            }
        },
        {
            title: 'Plus one?',
            text: 'Will you be bringing a plus one with you?',
            input: 'radio',
            inputOptions: {
                    'yes' : 'Yes',
                    'no' : 'No'
                },
            inputValidator: (value) => {
                return new Promise((resolve) => {
                    if (value === null) {
                        resolve('I need to know if you will be bringing a plus 1!')
                    } else if(value === 'yes') {


                        //EXTRA STAGE GOES HERE TO GET PLUS ONE NAME


                    } else {
                        resolve()
                    }
                })
            }
        },
        {
            title: 'What else?',
            input: 'text',
            text: 'Any other information that needs noting for this booking?'
        }
      ]).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            //Do something with all of the data here
        }
      })
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way would be to use a simple Swal instance for that extra optionnal step... And to keep the value in an aside variable declared globally.

```
var plus1name="";
```

In the sake of clarity, I won't repeat all your code, since unchanged. Here is a new part to add:

```
//EXTRA STAGE GOES HERE TO GET PLUS ONE NAME
swal({
  title:"Plus one!",
  text:"What is his/her name?",
  input:"text"
}).then(function(value){
  plus1name = value;
  resolve();
});
```

Then in the `.then(result)` part:

```
//Do something with all of the data here

swalResults = result.value;
swalResults.push(plus1name.value)
console.log(swalResults);
```

So you have an array with all the answers. The extra question was pushed at the end of it, so the order in the array is not the order of asking...

I worked on it on [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/YvWWao?editors=0011).

Comment: Brilliant, makes logical sense. Thanks for your help!